# How to add image or link dynamically without hook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown, pagedown

There is a need to add image or link to my pagedown textarea. I know we are able to hook image or link event but i want to do that without hooking. For example; i have an image url like `files/home/sweet/home.jpg` and i don't know how to add this with markdown style to content of the textarea directly.

```
![enter image description here][1]

...

[1]: files/home/sweet/home.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my github ReadMe's in Markdown what works is the use of parenthesis to indicate the path of the image to be inserted:

```
![enter image description here](files/home/sweet/home.jpg)
```

Hope this helps.